# How to get the old value of a select input in blade laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a Select and this Select can open routes when the onchange event is triggered, everything works fine, but when the new Route has opened, the Select entry initialized and revert to the first option "choose rib".
Here is my code:

```
<select name="choose_rib" class="form-control" id="choose_rib" 
        onchange="top.location.href =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="/rib/{{app('id')}}" {{ old('choose_rib') == 'rib/'.app('id') ? 'selected' : '' }}> 
        choose something 
    </option>
    
    @foreach ($ribs as $rib)
            <option value="/rib/{{ $rib->code_rib }}"  {{ old('choose_rib') == 'rib/'.$rib->code_rib ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                {{$rib->desig}}
            </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

in my controller :

```
public function goTo(Request $request)
{  
    $ribs = DB::select('select desig, rib from myTable');
    return view('show', compact('ribs'));
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this {{request () -> path ()}} to get the current url and compare the option value, like this(it's work fine) :

```
<option value="/rib/{{ $rib->code_rib }}" {{ request()->path() == 'rib/'.$rib->code_rib ? 'selected' : ''}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the `option` value to `{{ request()->route()->uri }}` - something like:

```
<option value="/rib/{{ $rib->code_rib }}"  {{ request()->route()->uri == 'rib/'.$rib->code_rib ? 'selected' : ''}}>
```

Note that it's bad practice to use form elements for navigation and you'd probably find it far easier using plain html links (with js to show/hide a 'dropdown' if need be).

Comment: it did not work, when I use dd(request()->route()->uri)  it's give me "rib/{id}" not the current URL like "rib/1"